# compare two array and store uncommon strings in new array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Below I have two arrays with values.

Array 1 - reorder_str

```
Array ( 
    [0] => A aacomputational agent is considered intelligent if it can adapt its actions to a particular setting. 
    [1] => A eecomputational agent is considered intelligent if it can adapt its actions to a particular setting. 
    [2] => defined 
    [3] => defined 
    [4] => defined 
)
```

Array 2 -reorder1

```
Array ( 
    [0] => A bbcomputational agent is considered intelligent if it can adapt its actions to a particular setting. 
    [1] => A cccomputational agent is considered intelligent if it can adapt its actions to a particular setting. 
    [2] => A aacomputational agent is considered intelligent if it can adapt its actions to a particular setting. 
    [3] => A ddcomputational agent is considered intelligent if it can adapt its actions to a particular setting. 
    [4] => A eecomputational agent is considered intelligent if it can adapt its actions to a particular setting.
)

<?php if(in_array($reorder1[0], $reorder_str)){
 ?>
    <div class="qitem di">
        1.<?php echo $reorder1[0];?>
    </div>
    <?php }?>
```

My expected output array3

```
Array ( 
        [0] => A bbcomputational agent is considered intelligent if it can adapt its actions to a particular setting. 
        [1] => A cccomputational agent is considered intelligent if it can adapt its actions to a particular setting. 
         [2] => A ddcomputational agent is considered intelligent if it can adapt its actions to a particular setting. 
    )
```

I Want to show the string if it is not present in array(reorder_str).I tried like this but its not working out.
My array 3 should store Uncommon strings from two array and new show not have any empty or undefined value.Thanks in advance.Meanwhile I tried with `array_diff` ,`in_array` but I couldn't get exact answer.

Comment: please post some code

Comment: See my updated question

Comment: can you please provide us expected output?

Comment: See my question now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this code as per your expected output,

```
$arr1 = array(
    0 => "A aacomputational agent is considered intelligent if it can adapt its actions to a particular setting.",
    1 => "A eecomputational agent is considered intelligent if it can adapt its actions to a particular setting.",
    2 => "defined ",
    3 => "defined ",
    4 => "defined ",
);
$arr1 = array_map('trim', $arr1);
$arr2 = array(
    "0" => "A bbcomputational agent is considered intelligent if it can adapt its actions to a particular setting.",  
    "1" => "A cccomputational agent is considered intelligent if it can adapt its actions to a particular setting.",  
    "2" => "A aacomputational agent is considered intelligent if it can adapt its actions to a particular setting.",  
    "3" => "A ddcomputational agent is considered intelligent if it can adapt its actions to a particular setting.",  
    "4" => "A eecomputational agent is considered intelligent if it can adapt its actions to a particular setting."
);
$arr2 = array_map('trim', $arr2);
$result = array_diff($arr2,$arr1);
print_r($result);
```

Here is working [link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0d37b9fc27be36c5eee58154924d42960f28d6e6)

Comment: For me its returned all values from arr2 array.

Comment: Have you checked link I have shared in my answer ?

Comment: Ya I had checked the link.But its returned me diff output

Comment: Check my updated code once, I have added trim to all values of both array

Comment: Array ( [1] => A bbcomputational agent is considered intelligent if it can adapt its actions to a particular setting. [2] => A cccomputational agent is considered intelligent if it can adapt its actions to a particular setting. [3] => A ddcomputational agent is considered intelligent if it can adapt its actions to a particular setting.

Comment: Its returned in output like this how to arrange in 0,1,2 form of array value

Comment: simple.. replace this line $result = array_diff($arr2,$arr1);
with $result = array_values(array_diff($arr2,$arr1)); Give it a try, this will work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136956/discussion-between-kavya-shree-and-rahul-m).